# Adding values to a dropdown <select> box using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a issue with populating values in a  box using JQuery.

Instead of adding it underneath each other it adds it next to all other elements

my code

```
$('#pages option').append($('#t1').val());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want

```
$('#pages').append($('#t1').val());
```

assuming pages is the id of your `<select>`. Also, `$('#t1').val()` should be an `<option>` element, not a value. Something like this

```
 var newOption = $('<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>');
 $('#pages').append(newOption);
```

or

```
var newOption = $('<option>');
newOption.attr('value',val).text(val);
 $('#pages').append(newOption);
```

whichever is easier for you to read.

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/uwevo)**

Comment: Yes it is the id of the select

Comment: Your code works but it's adding the element, but I'm not able to selected that element

Comment: The value does not get an option tag 

eg value and not <option>value</option>

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something along the lines of

```
$("#pages").append("<option>"+$("#t1").val()+"</option>");
```

That will make and append an option to your select box

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

using jquery you can use

```
  this.$('select#myid').append('<option>newvalue</option>');
```

where "**myid**" is the **id** of the dropdown list and **newvalue** is the text that you want to insert..